# Перенаправление трафика на другой локальный IP

Tags: ip, proxy, wifi, router, lan

Суть задачи:
Есть два компьютера PC1, PC2
У этих пк условно такие ip адреса: PC1 - 192.168.0.112, PC2 - 192.168.0.113
На некоторых роутерах записываеться трафик, и с какого ip адреса был выход в интернет.
Пользователю нужно сделать так, что бы при выходе с PC1 отображался ip адрес PC2 (при выходе в интернет с  192.168.0.112 на роутере должно отображаться как будто вышли с  192.168.0.113)
Как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: Ос на pc2 какая?

Comment: На основном пк Винда

Comment: да без разницы что на основном. на PC2 спрашиваю..) и куда хочется выходить - серфинг?

Comment: И Пк 2 - Винда)

Comment: тип трафика который хочешь получить с интернета какой? админские права есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно попробовать с прокси сервером. Например старая добрая [FreeProxy Internet Suite](https://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/index.php?page=download) или ручной Squid. Ставится на PC2 и прописывается в браузере на PC1.

Второй вариант - в свойствах подключения на втором ПК поставить "разрешить совместный доступ к интернет" и указать его IP как шлюз на первом ПК. Но может не заработать потому что Первый находится в подсети со шлюзом.

3 вариант - как второй, только кинуть реальный или виртуальный провод в котором создать новую сеть.

Comment: Благодарю за столь развернутый ответ))